# Data Lineage Report in hadoop

Tags: python, django, hadoop

I'm working on an ELT Tool using the Python-Django Framework.

In that tool, we can schedule the job and publish it in the Apache Oozie.

I need to Implement the Data Lineage Report for each job. In general, I've explored, "what is Data Lineage" in wiki.

I need help - how should I implement this Data lineage? Without using any external tools and Apache Falcon.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using Python-Django Framework and are doing most of your job scheduling using Oozie it is suggested to use the Lineage tracking using Falcon. It is easy to use and track lineage in the hadoop ecosystem.

However, if you wish not to use Apache Falcon you can always implement any Graph Database (Neo4J or TitanDB) and draw the graph using D3.js. For doing so you need to store the lineage (graph) variables in the GraphDB in a specific pattern. Once everything is set in the GraphDB it is easy to write D3 java scripts to retrieve them and draw the graph.

You can read more about D3 here:

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/index.html